# reverse of a string in web methods?

Tags: webmethods, webmethods-caf

I want  Reverse of a string in web methods development . If i give input string,i  want reverse of that input  string in web methods flow steps.

```
  ex:  input is            :  web methods
       expecting output as :  sdohtem bew
```

Comment: what do you actually mean by web methods?

Comment: web methods is middle ware technology .

Answer (score 3):

Simplest and most performant way is writting a small and simple Java service. Don't try writting this in Flow, way too complex.

Answer (score 1):

WebMethods is used for far more important stuffs than these.
I am not saying they are not possible, what i am telling is that flow service is not used for this purpose.
There is a REASON why webMethods has given us an option to use "JAVA SERVICE" .
Tasks like the one which you have mentioned can be performed efficiently with a simple JAVA service.

Anyways, if you want to do it using flowservice, do as below

1. Get the length of incoming String and map it to a variable called strLen and lastIndex
2. reduce the value of strlen by 1. [This will be used as a REPEAT COUNT]

3.Initialize a string called "finalString" , startIndex to Zero.

4.Insert a repeat step, repeat on success, using strlen as COUNT

INSIDE THE REPEAT STEP:

5.Insert a map step, insert a transformer pub.math:subtractInts .
map the lastIndex to input1, "1" to input2 and the result to "startIndex"

6.Invoke the service ,pub.string:substring
map the inputString to inString, beginIndex = startindex, endIndex=lastIndex, value = tempString

7.Concat finalString+tempString =finalString using the concat service. Drop the tempString

8.Reduce lastIndex by 1

[Sample Image of the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT3lj.png)

As said, stuffs like these are not intended to be done by FLOW SERVICE

Comment: Please try to properly format the text after "INSIDE THE REPEAT STEP." It's a bit unclear what's going on there.